# Read linked list using sequence files

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linked-list, kernel-module

I'm trying to implement linked list (or circular linked list as it is defined in `<linux/list.h>`) traversal in linux kernel using sequence files while I want to print data from all nodes to seq file and read them in user space application. I'm not a big fan of C programming so I don't understand how to achieve this. I know how to read/write to proc file using procfs (read/write) functions. Right now I'm using those, so when client application asks for data from linux kernel in proc read function I simply go through the list and store all data in buffer which I later copy to user. Problem is that this buffer may overflow, that's why I want to use seq files.

I understand basic concept of seq files, but I don't know how to exactly do list traversal and printing as I can't pass pointer to my node structure to iterating function.

This is struct which represents linked list's node:

```
struct my_data {
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned char action;
    struct list_head list;
};
```

These are my definitions for seq_file operations

```
static void *seq_start(struct seq_file *s, loff_t *pos)
{
    /* The entire data structure for this iterator is a single loff_t 
     * value holding the current position.
     */
    loff_t *spos = kmalloc(sizeof(loff_t), GFP_KERNEL);

    if (!spos)
        return NULL;

    *spos = *pos;

    return spos;
}

static void *seq_next(struct seq_file *s, void *v, loff_t *pos)
{
    return pos;
}

static void seq_stop(struct seq_file *s, void *v)
{
}

static int seq_show(struct seq_file *s, void *v)
{
    seq_printf(s, "print stuff\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Now to the point. I would really appreciate if someone enlighten me how to iterate over linked list using `seq_next()` function and how to access data stored in nodes in `seq_show()`.

Comment: There are only about a hundred examples in the Linux kernel of how to use seq files to display the contents of linked list. fs/proc is a good start.

Comment: Have you read [Documentation/filesystems/seq_file.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/seq_file.txt)? Particularly, pay attention to `seq_list_*()` functions. You can find those functions usage in kernel and use found code as example. For example, see next files: [drivers/input/input.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/input.c), [drivers/char/misc.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/misc.c).

Comment: @SamProtsenko This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for pointing in right direction

Answer (score 2):

```
struct list_head test_head;   //head of the link list


static void *seq_start(struct seq_file *s, loff_t *pos)
{
    return seq_list_start(&test_head, *pos);  
}

static void *seq_next(struct seq_file *s, void *v, loff_t *pos)
{
    return seq_list_next(v, &test_head, pos);
}

static int seq_show(struct seq_file *s, void *v)
{
    struct my_data *entry;
    entry = list_entry(v, struct my_data, _list);
    seq_printf(seq, "id = %u and action = %u\n", entry->id, entry->action);
    return 0;
}
```

seq_list_start and seq_list_next functions have been implemented in fs\seq_file.c